# C# TextBox shows only 1 line of string, but Debug.WriteLine shows it correctly

Tags: c#, debugging, foreach, textbox

```
foreach (HtmlNode href in DOCMAIN.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))                              //GETTING MATCHES INFO
             {
                // Get the value of the HREF attribute                   
                string hrefValue = href.GetAttributeValue("href", string.Empty);                   
                                                     Debug.WriteLine(hrefValue);

             }
```

Immediate Window showing all of string data (Multiple LInes) ,but if i try to export it to txt file or set Text to textbox, it automatically showing 1 line of data.
EDIT:

badly formulated question, the above code in Debug.WriteLine shows the whole value of the string about 60 lines, while the conversion debug to WriteLine, on TextBox.Text = hrefValue shows only 1 line

Comment: Is the TextBox set to Multiline??

Comment: Why would an href attribute contain more than one line?

Comment: I'ts already mulitline, Crowcoder its generating it i mean lines, i need to find the solution to actively saving this generated lines to txt or textbox.

Comment: The immediate window enforces the line splitting/text wrap, misleading you into believing there actually are multiple lines; since the string probably doesn't contain spaces it doesn't happen in the TextBox and of course it doesn't happen in a file.. No showing the code for the other output variations makes it impossible to help beyonf speculation!

Comment: But if i want to save save full string hrefValue to txt file or assign it text data to TextBox, I am seeing only 1 line, its contains much more

Comment: badly formulated question, the above code in Debug.WriteLine shows the whole value of the string about 60 lines, while the conversion debug to WriteLine, on TextBox.Text = hrefValue shows only 1 line . The problem is that TextBox and smiliar types of text obejcts cant show full data of hrefValue string

Comment: The rough equivalent of Debug.WriteLine() is TextBox.AppendText().  So you don't lose the previous text.

Comment: Already solved thanks to TaW

Answer (score 0):

```
textBox1.Text += System.Environment.NewLine + hrefValue;
```

Solved by adding line each foreach loop.
Thanks to TaW for tip about immediate window

Comment: Do avoid making this as expensive as you possibly could.  Use AppendText() instead.  And make sure it doesn't get out of hand, you *do* have to throw away old lines of text when you add too much, TextBox gets awfully inefficient with too much text.  Exact same kind of mishap as you'd get with System.String, you don't have a StringBuilder equivalent.  It is in fact StringBuilder that is the correct solution here, it makes no sense to update the textbox inside the foreach loop.